# Route audio to earpiece?

Tags: iphone, audio

Is it  possible to route audio such as a local mp3 file to play through the iPhone earpiece instead of speakerphone?

Comment: if the headphones are plugged in, isn't the audio automatically routed to the headphones?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, yet a bit complicated as it appears. You might want to check the paragraph **Audio Session Category Route Overrides** in the [Audio Sessions Services Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/AudioSessionServicesReference/Reference/reference.html), to get into the matter.